# Finding the probability that $A$ occurs before $B$

Tags: probability

Given an experiment has $3$ possible outcomes $A, B$ and $C$ with respective probabilities $p, q$ and $r$ where $p + q + r = 1.$ The experiment is repeated until either outcome $A$ or outcome $B$ occurs. How can I show that $A$ occurs before B with probability $\dfrac{p}{p+q}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can compute. We get $A$ before $B$ if we get $A$, or $CA$, or $CCA$, or $CCCA$ and so on.

The probability of $A$ is $p$. The probability of $CA$ is $rp$. The probability of $CCA$ is $r^2p$, and so on. So the required probability is
$$p(1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots).$$
If $r\ne 1$, then by the usual formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series, our probability is $\frac{p}{1-r}$, which is $\frac{p}{p+q}$.

Comment: This is correct but I think my solution is more elegant ;)

Comment: Yes, your way is more elegant. I wrote we can compute at the beginning to stress that an answer can be found semi-mechanically. Your way, which is better, is, for people not accustomed to conditioning on the result of the first toss, much less mechanical.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ denote the given probability. Then by independence, we see that $$a = p + ra,$$
which yields
$$a = \frac p{1-r}= \frac p{p+q}. $$

Comment: Could you be more specific with line $a = p + ra$?

Comment: Condition on the result of the first toss. You either get $A$ with probability $p$, $B$ (in which case you don't get $A$ before $B$), or $C$ with probability $r$, which leads to the same situation as you were before the first toss.

Answer (score 0):

The occurrences of $C$ are irrelevant in deciding whether $A$ comes before $B$ or vice versa,

hence the desired $Pr = \frac p{p+q}$